# My calendar is not show the model date value ,when I press edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, datetime

I am create form of accept start date and end date. When create button press it accept value in datetime and user see calendar format for input date. But when I click to edit, the form show all details except the date.

Here my code.

Model:

```
public DateTime whenEntred { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

public DateTime whenModified { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Edit :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.startDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control startDate", @autoComplete = "off", @type = "date", @required = "required" } })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.startDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.endDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control endDate", @autoComplete = "off", @type = "date", @required = "required" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.endDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to show date in calendar format also user can edit that date.
What changes I have to Do? Please help.

(In Inspect the edit show as:
`<input autocomplete="off" class="form-control startDate text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Start Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Start Date field is required." id="startDate" name="startDate" required="required" type="date" value="01-08-2022 00:00:00">`)

Answer (score 3):

This is because `input type="date"` accepts `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

You can first convert date format to `yyyy-MM-dd` before passing it to view.

`Model Class`

```
public class EditVM
{
    // Add using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; on top of the model class
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public string startDate { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public string endDate { get; set; }
}
```

Model you pass it to view, convert datatype of `startDate and endDate` to `string`

`Controller`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int Id)
{
    var model = ...;
    model.startDate = model.startDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    model.endDate = model.endDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is because input type="date" accepts yyyy-MM-dd format.
You can in the view add the format expected as follows:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fromDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { type="date", @class = "form-control",value = @Model.fromDate })
```

in the model you can leave the datetime type

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach to achieve this is by modifying the data during the binding process on the designer side, as illustrated below.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbDate" TextMode="Date" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("YourColumnData", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>' CssClass="w-auto"></asp:TextBox>
```